# Clojure: filtering with a function of multiple args

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a some data as follows

```
;authors
(def china {:name "China Miéville", :birth-year 1972})
(def octavia {:name "Octavia E. Butler"
              :birth-year 1947
              :death-year 2006})
(def friedman {:name "Daniel Friedman" :birth-year 1944})
(def felleisen {:name "Matthias Felleisen"})

;books
(def cities {:title "The City and the City" :authors #{china}})
(def wild-seed {:title "Wild Seed", :authors #{octavia}})
(def embassytown {:title "Embassytown", :authors #{china}})
(def little-schemer {:title "The Little Schemer"
                     :authors #{friedman, felleisen}})

(def books [cities, wild-seed, embassytown, little-schemer])
```

So If I want to check if a given book has author I use the function

```
(defn has-author? [book author]
  (contains? (:authors book) author)
)
```

But I want to get books from a particular author how do i get it by filter? I tried:

```
(defn books-by-author [author books]
 (filter has-author? (books author))
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `filter` in `books-by-author` to pass a predicate defined in terms of `has-author?` along with the books collection, where each book is referenced by the predicate:

```
(filter #(has-author? % author) books)
```

Answer (score 1):

reverse the parameters, it makes things more tractable

```
(defn has-author? [author book]
  (contains? (:authors book) author))
```

then you can do

```
(defn books-by-author [books author]
 (filter (partial has-author? author) books))
```